# I want to redirect to different pages based on some condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

when i run this code i get redirect to postUser page when i want to redirect if condition is true and render view if condition is false...

```js
router.get('/postedUser/:id', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (req.user._id == data._id) {
      res.redirect('/users/profile');
    } else {
      res.render('postedUser', {
        data: data
      });
    }
  });
});
```

can some one tell me where am going wrong..

Comment: This seems to be an issue with MongoDBs ObjectIds not being Strings, please make sure, that `req.user._id` and `data._id` are of the same type when using `===`

Comment: when i use '==' comparison operator still i am redirecting to postedUser page

Comment: Yes, make sure that both have the same type. Either use `.toString()` on both, or log their typeof's and make sure that they match

Comment: Thanks man it works now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data to HTML page and how to use AJAX for Single Page Application in NodeJS Server using express.js framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967362/how-to-send-data-to-html-page-and-how-to-use-ajax-for-single-page-application-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do so if you are submitting request using an API call from Ajax or other methods.

As all these methods are to implement **Single Page Application**, so rendering a different page is not allowed.

What happens when condition is met and request to render a different page?

The module who called API is waiting for response on browser to get some response from API, however your API is trying to load a different HTML page which browser prohibits and thus you will never get rendered via Ajax call.

How to do it?

There are two way out:

1. Single Page Application: Using JavaScript Frameworks like AngularJs, ReactJs will help you out by just changing HTML templates and not whole page.

With Ajax you can do this:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div>   
        <div align="center">
        <form id="form1">
            <label>Please enter below details</label><br><br>
            <label>First Name *: </label><input id="FName" type="text" name="FName"/><br><br>
            <label>Last Name *: </label><input id="LName" type="text" name="LName"/><br><br>         
            <label>Email Address *: </label><input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick:"submitForm()"/>
        </form>
        <div id="showValue"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addName',
        type: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        data: {
            "Fname": $("#FName").val(),
            "Lname": $("#LName").val(),
            "email": $("#email").val()
        },
        success: function(result) {
            //append result to your html
            //Dynamic view
            $("#form1").hide();
            var html = '<div><span>First Name: ' + result.fName + '</span><span>Last Name: ' + result.lName + '</span></div>';
            $("#showValue").html(html);    
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('error ',error);
        }
    });
}
```

Server side code I'm assuming you are using express.js and body-parser

```
app.post('/addName', (req, res) => {
    //Insert into db
    var body = req.body;
    res.send({
    fName: body.FName,
    lName: body.LName
    });
});
```

2. Use `form` Submit method: using this you will be able to render the page however you can't send response back to same page i.e.,

HTML

```
<body>
    <div>   
        <div align="center">
        //Can't send params using this approach
        //Data will be send as query string
        <form action="/postedUser/" method="GET">
            <label>Please enter below details</label><br><br>
            <label>ID *: </label><input id="ID" type="text" name="ID"/><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

NodeJS

```
//If there will be res.send({});
// This won't be returned to same page. But your code doesn't do any such thing

router.get('/postedUser/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
   User.findOne({_id: req.query.id}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (req.user._id == data._id) {
        res.redirect('/users/profile');
        } else {
        res.render('postedUser', {
            data: data
        });
        }
    });
});
```